# Cannot stop alarm from ringing even pressed the stop button

Tags: java, android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I am having trouble to stop the alarm from ringing even after I have pressed the stopAlarm button. thank you for any help.

This is my start alarm switch in MainActivity java class.

```
public void switchClicked (View view) {
        if (((Switch) view).isChecked()) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Alarm On");
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmTimePicker.getHour());
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmTimePicker.getMinute());
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            setAlarmText("ON");
        } else {
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            setAlarmText("OFF");
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Alarm Off");
        }
    }
    public void setAlarmText(String alarmText) {
        alarmTextView.setText(alarmText);
    }
```

Here is my StopAlarm button in MainActivity java class.

```
public void stopAlarm(View view) {
        setAlarmText("Alarm stopped");
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            }
```

This is the AlarmReciver java class.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        MainActivity inst = MainActivity.instance();
        inst.setAlarmText("Alarm! Wake up! Wake up!");
        Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        if (alarmUri == null) {
            alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        }
        Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
        ringtone.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the tags, on the left. You may need to use a browser, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

You are using `getService()` but you should use `getBroadcast()` instead.

Why?

[`getService()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getService(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)) retrieves a PendingIntent that will start a service, but since you are using a `BroadcastReceiver` you should use [`getBroadcast()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)) that retrieves a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but it did not seem to work. The alarm still kept ringing after I pressed the Stop button. Do you know any other way that would make the button work? Thank you for any help @Skizo-ozᴉʞS.

Comment: Post github or something

Comment: Ok, I will reply to you as soon as it is uploaded. Again, thank you so much for the help.

Comment: This is the link to it. Thanks. https://github.com/rabbitroc/Quiz-alarm

Comment: I'm not able to listen the sound though, how I'm suposed to activate the alarm?

Comment: Sometime you will need to wait a bit at the set time and turn on the alarm by switching the toggle on bottom left to on and you need to make sure phone is not on silent and if you are using the android emulator you need to make sure that setting - sound and make sure that there is a default alarm sound.